# List <T> Add Value Only If It Is Minimum Of All Elements

Tags: c#, list, generics

I have 2 statements as follows to plot a graph.

```
public static List<KeyValuePair<int, double>> entries = new List<KeyValuePair<int, double>>();
entries.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, double>(j, min));
```

What I want is  that the `min` value only gets added to the List if it is less than or equal to every other `min` values in the list.
How can this be achieved?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just calculate min value of all entries and check if it's bigger than your `min` value:

```
if (!entries.Any() || min <= entries.Min(e => e.Value))
   entries.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, double>(j, min));
```

UPDATE: you also need to check if there is any elements in entries list, before trying to find minimal value.

HINT: If you always use this rule for adding items and don't modify collection in other way (i.e. remove items or insert at some index) then you can simply check last item's value - it will always be less or equal to other values.

UPDATE: Instead of usage KeyValuePair for your data, you can create custom class with descriptive names for properties and class itself (you can consider even better names):

```
public class Point
{
    public Point(int iteration, double value)
    {
        Iteration = iteration;
        Value = value;
    }

    public int Iteration { get; private set; }
    public double Value { get; private set; }
}
```

And then create class which encapsulates points and behavior related to these points. From your description it could be something like:

```
public class DecresingGraph
{
    private List<Point> points = new List<Point>();

    public void Add(Point point)
    {
        if (!points.Any())
        {
            points.Add(point);
            return;
        }

        if (point.Value <= points.Last().Value)
            points.Add(point);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Point> Points 
    {
        get { return points; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an Sequence contains no elements exception.

Comment: @Debojyoti updated - you should check if there is any entries to get minimal one from them. Btw what kind of data you store in this list?

Comment: Values for graphical points. even if I add a `entries.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, double>(1, 0.0));` an exception is thrown.

Comment: @Debojyoti why one value is integer and another is double?

Comment: Yup. One value is iteration count other mathematical data.

Comment: @Debojyoti Funny you're accepting this answer as it is slightly wrong as it would be adding 0 twice for example :)

Comment: @AndreasMüller according to requirements, you can add 0 three times or more

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy You're right. Apparently i failed at reading there.

Comment: Then again i still don't understand why you'd just blindly use linq everywhere. You'll just iterate over everything for no good reason. Just a waste of performance really.

Comment: @AndreasMüller actually I don't use LINQ blindly :) [LINQ checks if source implements IList](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs.html#75722fd194dc2e0e) and if so, then it use indexer to access last item. And I find `points.Last().Value` very readable

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy You're right. Just decompiled to verify. In that case there's nothing wrong with your solution. I apologize for the unjustified criticism then :)

Comment: @AndreasMüller no problem :) Btw you don't need to decompile now - use reference source site (I added link) to see sources of .NET. And you are right about checking `Count == 0` it would be faster than `Any()`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Haha thanks, very thorough of you. I'm using resharper anyway so it's loading the sources anyway. Then again if someone else stumbles into this question he may also learn something new from your link, so it does not hurt.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Enumerable.Min](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.min%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to calculate minimum value and then compare it with the current value like:

```
var minValue = entries.Min(r => r.Value);
if (min <= minValue)
{
    entries.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, double>(j, min));
}
```

Comment: Almost at same time :) Just wondering - why you have chosen name `r` to KeyValuePair entry?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, just a habit

Comment: Comparison made between same variable!

Answer (score 2):

If performance matters you should be using this instead:

```
public class MinFloatKeyValuePairList : Collection<KeyValuePair<int, float>>
{
    private float _lowest = float.MaxValue;

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, KeyValuePair<int, float> item)
    {
        if (item.Value <= _lowest || this.Count == 0)
        {
            _lowest = item.Value;
            base.InsertItem(index, item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a collection that overrides InsertItem

```
public class YourCollection : Collection<KeyValuePair<int, double>>
{
   protected override void InsertItem(int index, KeyValuePair<int, double> item)
   {
      if (!this.Any() || item.Value <= this.Min(e => e.Value))
         base.InsertItem(index, item);
   }
}
```

Then you can just add your item in the collection, and the item will be added in the list if it fits your requirement.

```
YourCollection collection = new YourCollection();
collection.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, double>(j, min));
```